# Iterate all the property in object, find and replace

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript object generated from my code and player object is

```
const player = {
   cards: []
}
```

My question is how do I loop through all my card in player object and replace all the "A" faceValue to 1? Using findIndex or splice?

```
player: Object
cards: Array(2)
0: Array(1)
0: card {suit: "spades", face: "7", faceValue: 7}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
0: card {suit: "clubs", face: "A", faceValue: 11}
length: 1
1: Array(2)
0: card {suit: "spades", face: "A, faceValue: 11}
length: 1
```

Comment: write a loop, check if face is == A, if it is, set faceValue to 1

Comment: It's unclear what the structure of your data is (from the log output), so it's difficult to suggest a way to iterate over that structure.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your cards object to update its value

```
player.cards = player.cards.map(card => {
    if (card.face === 'A') card.faceValue = 1;
    return card;
});
```

Update:
It is better to use `forEach` if we are not generating new values

```
player.cards.forEach(card => {
    if (card.face === 'A') card.faceValue = 1;
});
```

Comment: No need to use `.map` if you mutate the objects (i.e. not generating new values). Just use `.forEach` then.

Comment: any example of .forEach to find and replace?

Comment: yes @FelixKling is right but mutating arrays is mostly a bad practice. I'd create a new one like `const myCards = player.cards.map(....)` and if needed assign that array to the player afterwards. Imho this is a better pattern, even if it may be slower